# access folder on root with wp installed

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have wordpress installed on the root . Now what i want that i will create one folder with the name of test and putt some files there and try to access it but i cant access the folder due to the htacess file i guess .

My htacess file is like this

```
RewriteEngine Off

SetEnv DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION 53

DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Folder stucture is like this

```
./wp-content
./wp-admin
./...
./...
./bot
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is an .htaccess issue, you can create another .htaccess file in your test folder and override the settings from its parent.

You may need to add the following to your parent .htaccess file in order to enable cascading:

```
 AllowOverride All
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#AllowOverride

Comment: thanks for the reply , no it didnt work with that . I am not sure where to fix that i doubt that it deal with the htacess